# Force current commit to tip of branch

Tags: git

So I reset to a previous commit that was 9 behind the current tip of the branch. I want to force push and ignore all of the changes ahead of my most recent commit. In other words I want to be able to push to tip of the branch without pulling. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just do (please backup your local repository before):

```
  # Switch to the branch
  git checkout YOUR_BRANCH_NAME
  # Reset tip of current branch to HEAD~9
  git reset --hard HEAD~9
  # Push force the new HEAD
  git push --force origin HEAD
```